# document.head.appendChild not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append jQuery library via JavaScript code like this:

```
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.type = 'text/javascript'
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'
    document.head.appendChild(script);

if (window.jQuery) {  
    document.write('jQuery is loaded') 
} else {
    document.write('jQuery is not loaded');
}
```

The above code is not executing the src file and I am not able to find jQuery element. To confirm I have added this piece of code:

```
if (window.jQuery) {  
    document.write('jQuery is loaded') 
} else {
    document.write('jQuery is not loaded');
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vyeyhrrL/

The output I am seeing is "jQuery is not loaded".

Can you let me know what I am missing?

Edit:

Thanks to comments, this is working:

```
    var script = document.createElement('script')
    script.type = 'text/javascript'
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js';
script.onload = function(script){
            console.log(script + ' loaded!');
if (window.jQuery) {  
    document.write('jQuery is loaded') 
} else {
    document.write('jQuery is not loaded');
}
        };
    document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: The script won't load immediately, so checking right after appending the `<script>` is not the right thing to do.

Comment: Can you point me how to load it?

Comment: Use `script.onload`.

Comment: script.onreadystatechange= function () {
      if (this.readyState == 'complete') helper();
   } try this